# How to know the status of each task executing in thread pool executor in java

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, threadpool, threadpoolexecutor

I am using Spring `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` to execute tasks. I want to know the status of the thread in `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`, like whether it is finished or in progress or completed. If the task executing thread fails I need to update the subsequent entry of task in taskInfo table to "failed". I have tried the `isAlive` method of thread to check the thread status but it is always returning true status. What is the best way to know the exact status of a thread in `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`.

Comment: How about using the built-in [`ListenableFuture`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.html#submitListenable-java.lang.Runnable-)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35571395/how-to-access-running-threads-inside-threadpoolexecutor/35572938#35572938.